# pandas dataframe how to sum all value of bigger columns per row

Tags: pandas, dataframe, data-science, data-munging

I have a dataframe:

```
0.  1. 2. 3
2.  3. 5. 9
5.  1. 0. 3
```

And for columns `1,2,3` - I want the value for each row to be the sum of higher columns
So the new df will be:

```
0. 1. 2. 3 
2. 17 14. 9
5. 4. 3. 3
```

What is the best way to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us try `cumsum` along `axis=1` after reverting the columns `1, 2, 3`:

```
c = [1, 2, 3]
df.loc[:, c] = df.loc[:, c[::-1]].cumsum(axis=1)
```

---

```
   0   1   2  3
0  2  17  14  9
1  5   4   3  3
```

Answer (score 2):

Use inverse [`DataFrame.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html):

```
L = [1,2,3]
df[L[::-1]] = df[L[::-1]].cumsum(axis=1)
print (df)
     0     1     2    3
0  2.0  17.0  14.0  9.0
1  5.0   4.0   3.0  3.0
```

Comment: I get the opposite: column 3 = 1+2+3 ; columns 2 = 1+2 ; and 1 = 1
instead of 1 = 1+2+3 ; 2 = 3+2 ; and 3=3.
I had a type in the original question that may have caused confusion, please see my edit

Comment: that the value of column x0 - is the sum of every column c, such that c >= x0